# Gathering of list

Tags: list-manipulation

**Problem statement**

The following challenge was recently posted to the J language programming forum by Skip Cave (http://jsoftware.com/pipermail/programming/2016-March/044561.html):

"The animal control officer wants to keep track of the animals in a city. The officer tags all the animals with a serial number. He keeps a list of all the animals he has tagged, along with each serial number."

In *Mathematica* form, the given list is:

```
    data = {{"bird", 1}, {"cow", 2}, {"cow", 3}, {"dog", 4}, {"cow", 5},   
            {"cow", 6}, {"cow", 7}, {"bird", 8}, {"dog", 9}, {"cat", 10},   
            {"dog", 11}, {"pig", 12}, {"dog", 13}, {"bird", 14}, {"pig", 15}};
```

"The officer now wants to make a second list showing each type of animal along with all the serial numbers tagged for each animal."

In *Mathematica* form, the desired output is:

```
    {{"bird", {1, 8, 14}}, {"cow", {2, 3, 5, 6, 7}}, 
     {"dog", {4, 9, 11, 13}}, {"cat", {10}}, {"pig", {12, 15}}}
```

The challenge is to transform the given input data into that output form in as simple a way as possible. (As phrased in the J Programming forum post, the challenge was to do so in as short an expression as possible.)

**My solution so far:**

```
    creatures = Union[First /@ data]
    gathered = GatherBy[data, First]
    serials = Map[Last, #] & /@ gathered
    Transpose[{creatures, serials}]
```

Naturally, multiple steps may be combined, e.g.:

```
    serials = Map[Last, #] & /@ GatherBy[data, First]
```

In fact, all steps could be combined into one long expression:

```
    Transpose[{Union[First /@ data], Map[Last, #] & /@ GatherBy[data, First]}]
```

Moreover, the list `serials` of lists of serial numbers could be formed using patterned replacement:

```
    serials = gathered /. {animal_, n_Integer} -> n
```

**Question**

Is there some significantly shorter or simpler way to do this?

**Notes**

1. The original data and desired output could have been cast into the form of associations, but I suspect the operations required to go from data to output would be essentially the same.
2. Probably the output should be fed into `SortBy[#, First]&` so as to rearrange the output list to be sorted alphabetically by animal name.

**P.S.**

Can you suggest a better, but succinct, title for my post?

Comment: Why not `Normal[GroupBy[data, First -> Last]] /. Rule -> List`?

Comment: @J. M.: OMG! Please post as answer.

Comment: @J. M.: I wonder if there's still some way, though, to avoid using `Association` as an intermediate structure.

Comment: @murray I don't know if it matters to you, but if you are after the shortest possible version, then the following slight modification of J.M.'s code will also work: `List@@@Normal@GroupBy[data, First -> Last]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using `Merge`:**

```
data = {{"bird", 1}, {"cow", 2}, {"cow", 3}, {"dog", 4}, {"cow", 
    5}, {"cow", 6}, {"cow", 7}, {"bird", 8}, {"dog", 9}, {"cat", 
    10}, {"dog", 11}, {"pig", 12}, {"dog", 13}, {"bird", 14}, {"pig", 
    15}};

Normal[Merge[Rule @@@ data, Identity]] /. Rule -> List
```

> {{"bird", {1, 8, 14}}, {"cow", {2, 3, 5, 6, 7}}, {"dog", {4, 9, 11,
> 13}}, {"cat", {10}}, {"pig", {12, 15}}}

Comment: Nice and short and clear!

Comment: Thanks @murray.

Answer (score 17):

As requested by the OP:

```
Normal[GroupBy[data, First -> Last]] /. Rule -> List
   {{"bird", {1, 8, 14}}, {"cow", {2, 3, 5, 6, 7}}, {"dog", {4, 9, 11, 13}},
    {"cat", {10}}, {"pig", {12, 15}}}
```

The handy bit here is the second argument of `GroupBy[]`:

```
GroupBy[data, First -> Last]
   <|"bird" -> {1, 8, 14}, "cow" -> {2, 3, 5, 6, 7}, "dog" -> {4, 9, 11, 13},
     "cat" -> {10}, "pig" -> {12, 15}|>
```

which transforms the values associated with the keys into the desired list of numbers. Contrast this with a plain `GroupBy[data, First]`.

As noted by multiple people, a more compact version is

```
List @@@ Normal[GroupBy[data, First -> Last]]
```

Tom in a comment below gives a slicker version:

```
KeyValueMap[List, GroupBy[data, First -> Last]]
```

---

The `GatherBy[]` approach presented by the OP can also be written as

```
Append[Union[#[[All, 1]]], #[[All, 2]]] & /@ GatherBy[data, First]
```

or as

```
Append @@ MapAt[Union, Transpose[#], 1] & /@ GatherBy[data, First]
```

Comment: OP edited so as to show correct "desired output".

Comment: The variant, `List @@@ Normal[GroupBy[data, First -> Last]]` is slightly shorter.

Comment: Just for fun: `Transpose@{Keys@#, Values@#} & @ GroupBy[data, First -> Last]`

Comment: Even more fun: `KeyValueMap[List, GroupBy[data, First -> Last]]`

Answer (score 11):

I think this is one of the simplest here, both conceptually and in code:

```
Reap[Sow @@@ Reverse[data, {2}], _, List][[2]]
```

Comment: in code, that is for sure, but conceptually it requires some comments :)) +1 as always...

Comment: @garej Conceptually, I consider tagging carried out by `Reap` - `Sow` the simplest and most direct idiom here. Using an assoc requires then to transform it later to lists (2 extra operations - `Normal` and replacement of a rule with a list - and either of these can go subtly wrong for more complex keys / values), which to me feels less natural.

Comment: I did not accept this answer since I had already accepted J. M.'s, and since I cannot yet penetrate what's going on in the `Reap`...`Sow` construction -- even after using `Trace` upon it!

Comment: @murray It's actually pretty simple. `Sow[expr, tag]` marks expression with the tag `tag`. In this case, I had to reverse inner lists, since I wanted to tag integer indices by animal names, so I needed an index to be the first and animal name to be the last in each inner list. Then `Reap[code, _, f]` collects together all parts that were tagged with a given tag in `code`, and applies `f[tag, collected-items]`, for each tag, and returns these in a `List`. Having it as `List` would just produce `{animal-name, {indices}}`, since we used animal names as tags.

Comment: @murray, if you feel that Leonid's answer is more suitable to your needs, feel free to shift the acceptance.

Comment: @J.M. Just to be clear on this: your solution is great, I upvoted it right after seeing. It is also more efficient than mine. What I said about simplicity is a relatively minor issue, and also very subjective. The following modifications  `List @@@ Normal[GroupBy[data, First -> Last]]`  or `Replace[Normal[GroupBy[data, First -> Last]], Rule -> List, {2},  
 Heads -> True]`,  will be more robust, if one wants to generalize the problem to arbitrary keys and values (which themselves may contain rules).

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence. :) Nevertheless, I wanted murray to know that I (and I believe most of us here as well) wouldn't take it against them if they shift the acceptance to another answer that they feel is more suitable for them. I'll make the change you suggested a little later.

Comment: The most educational approach here for me +1

Answer (score 5):

```
MapAt[#[[1]]&, Transpose/@ GatherBy[data, First], {;; , 1}]
```

> {{"bird", {1, 8, 14}}, {"cow", {2, 3, 5, 6, 7}}, {"dog", {4, 9, 11, 13}}, {"cat", {10}}, {"pig", {12, 15}}}

**Edit**
Corrected by murray, aka OP:

```
MapAt[Last, Transpose/@ GatherBy[data, First], {;; , 1}]
```

**Edit2** Just for the ad hoc case with specific numeration `PositionIndex`:

```
List @@@ Normal @ PositionIndex[data[[All, 1]]]
```

Comment: This answer becomes a bit simpler if you replace `#[[1]]&` by `First`.

Comment: @murray, you are rigth. Why you didn't like the Reap-Sow solution?

Comment: It's not that I don't like the Reap-Sow solution, it's that I do not yet understand it. The indexing `[[2]]` there is the trivial part that I do understand. My difficulty is I have not yet found a satisfactorily complete explanation about "tagging" that allows `Reap` to return not just the final result, which that indexing throws away, but more importantly the rest of the final output.