# How to merge data?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have some group of data with different classes,in the form of below:

> {{2, 3} -> 1, {1, 5} -> 1,  {1, 1} -> 2, {2, 2} -> 2}

I need to merge the data of same class.Like this:

> {1->{ {2,3},{1,5}},2->{{1,1},{2,2}} }

`Merge[#[[2]] -> #[[1]] & /@ a, List]` 
This doesn't work well.

Comment: First, apply Association to your data, then use GroupBy[Identity].

Comment: Normal[GroupBy[list, Last->First]]

Comment: @erow, `Merge[#[[2]] -> #[[1]] & /@ a, Apply@List]`

Comment: Is this close enough to be a duplicate? [Gathering of list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109104/5478)

Comment: You did not explain why the `Merge` you show did not work well.  To get the exact output you show, use `Merge[Reverse /@ a, Identity]`, with `Normal` applied to the result.  The `GroupBy` approach of @TheYeda is likely to be (much) faster though.

Comment: I just bother about this way.I need to Normal,then Flatten.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the straightforward way `GroupBy`

```
Normal@GroupBy[{{2, 3} -> 1, {1, 5} -> 1, {1, 1} -> 2, {2, 2} -> 2}, Last -> First]

(* {1 -> {{2, 3}, {1, 5}}, 2 -> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}} *)
```

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
list = {{2, 3} -> 1, {1, 5} -> 1, {1, 1} -> 2, {2, 2} -> 2};
Map[# -> SequenceCases[list, {pat : PatternSequence[_ -> #]} :> First@pat] &, 
Union@list[[All, 2]]]

(* {1 -> {{2, 3}, {1, 5}}, 2 -> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}} *)
```

Using pattern in `ReplaceRepeated` (this will work if at most two entries per index i.e. 1 -> or 2 -> are present)

```
{{2, 3} -> 1, {1, 5} -> 1, {1, 1} -> 2, {2, 2} -> 2} //. {w___, pat1_ -> x_,
y___, pat2_ -> x_, z___} :> {w, x -> {pat1, pat2} y, z}

(* {1 -> {{2, 3}, {1, 5}}, 2 -> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}} *)
```

**More general form of `ReplaceRepeated` (works with more than two entries)**

```
list= {{2, 3} -> 2, {1, 5} -> 1, {1, 1} -> 2, {2, 2} -> 1, {3, 3} -> 2};

list//. {{w___, pat1_ -> x_, y___, pat2_ -> x_, z___} :> {w, x -> {pat1, pat2}, y, z},
{w___, x_ -> {pat1 : {__} ..}, y___, pat2_ -> x_, z___} :> {w, x -> {pat1, pat2}, y, z}}

(* {2 -> {{2, 3}, {1, 1}, {3, 3}}, 1 -> {{1, 5}, {2, 2}}} *)
```

Comment: It's hard to understand.

Comment: @erow use the straightforward way for now. As you will explore some aspects of the language more (patterns and rules etc..) I am sure the two methods will fall into place. The purpose here is to show that there are multiple ways of achieving the task.

Answer (score 6):

```
data = {{2, 3} -> 1, {1, 5} -> 1, {1, 1} -> 2, {2, 2} -> 2};

#[[1, -1]] -> #[[All, 1]] & /@ GatherBy[data, Last]

(*  {1 -> {{2, 3}, {1, 5}}, 2 -> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}}  *)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
a = {{2, 3} -> 1, {1, 5} -> 1, {1, 1} -> 2, {2, 2} -> 2}

Merge[Reverse /@ a, Apply[List]]
```

Answer (score 5):

In:

```
xss = {{2, 3} -> 1, {1, 5} -> 1, {1, 1} -> 2, {2, 2} -> 2};
(*Method 1*)
xss // Map[Reverse] // Merge[#, Join] & // Normal

(*Method 2*)
values = Last /@ xss // Union;
positions[x_] := Position[SparseArray[xss] // Normal, x]
valueToRule[x_] := Rule[x, positions[x]]
values // Map[valueToRule]
```

Out:

```
{1 -> {{2, 3}, {1, 5}}, 2 -> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}}
{1 -> {{1, 5}, {2, 3}}, 2 -> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {{2, 3} -> 1, {1, 5} -> 1, {1, 1} -> 2, {2, 2} -> 2};
data1 = data /. ({x_, y_} -> z_) -> {z -> {x, y}};
Merge[Flatten[Tally[data1][[All, 1]]], Identity]
```